# SVN Branch info from Java

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I'm looking for a way to extract info on all branches within a repository.
I'm only interesteted in the name of the branches.

I have tried to play around with [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/), but haven't been able to figure out, how to get this information.

Comment: did you read this `getLogClient() ` http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNClientManager.html and this http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNLogClient.html `doLog()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repository structure is known, you may use either `SVNLogClient.doList(SVNURL, SVNRevision, SVNRevision, boolean, boolean, ISVNDirEntryHandler)` or you may go with the more low-level `SVNRepository` API directly. Have a look at the *listEntries* example at:

http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree

Answer (score 3):

From the [svnbook, chapter 4](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.using.html):

> You should remember two important lessons from this section. **First, Subversion has no internal concept of a branch**—it knows only how to make copies. When you copy a directory, the resultant directory is only a “branch” because you attach that meaning to it. You may think of the directory differently, or treat it differently, but to Subversion it's just an ordinary directory that happens to carry some extra historical information.
>
> Second, because of this copy mechanism, Subversion's **branches exist as normal filesystem directories in the repository**. This is different from other version control systems, where branches are typically defined by adding extra-dimensional “labels” to collections of files. The location of your branch directory doesn't matter to Subversion. Most teams follow a convention of putting all branches into a /branches directory, but you're free to invent any policy you wish.

To get the branch names, you need to know information on the internat structure of a repository. I doubt, that there is a general approach to *get all branches* - as they are nothing but local copies.

Comment: Ah ok.
The structure is known. Its our own repo. There is a /branch folder
So I need to enter the /branch folder and retrieve all the names.

Answer (score -1):

Do ctrl+3 in your eclipse (BTW my favourite Eclipse shortcut), and type repositories, this should give you the option to open your SVN repository view.

Once the view is opened, if your repository is not added, add it... Once that is added you will be able to expand it and browse it as a normal directory tree and you will be able to see the name of all your branches

Comment: You misunderstood me. Im not looking for the feature in Eclipse.
Im looking for a way to access this in code. I can then print out the list of bracnhes or something else.

Comment: oops... Sorry... yeah I don't know how to do that :(